# Force Named Credential to get a new access token using Apex

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

I'm using a Named Credential with OAuth2 to call a SOAP API. This API returns an HTTP 500 after the token is expired, but a Named Credential can only automatically refresh the access token when a 401 status is returned. There is no other endpoint on the domain of the Named Credential that does return a 401.

Is there any way to force the Named Credential to refesh its access token from Apex?

Comment: No, you'll have to do this in Apex without NC.